# when date is empty don't show 01-01-1970

Tags: php, web-services, validation, date

I am consuming a webservice in php. The piece of code below gives me the following european format result with regard to the date notation:
Begindatum : 01-01-2011
Einddatum : 01-01-1970
The einddatum (end date) is for some reason set to 01-01-1970 when there is none/the webservice value is empty. I would like it to stay empty when none is given, but how?

Help is appreciated.

regards
Peter

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
print "
<tr>
      <td>
            <ul>
                <li><b>Begindatum   : " . date("d-m-Y",strtotime($v->Begindatum)) ."</b></li>
                <li><b>Einddatum    : " . date("d-m-Y",strtotime($v->Einddatum)) ."</b></li>
            </ul>
      </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: any reason you can't simply do "empty($v->Begindatum) ? '' : date('d-m-Y',strtotime($v->Begindatum))" ?

Comment: does not work with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtotime` returns `false` on failure (for an empty string for example), so you can check for that:

```
$begin = strtotime($v->Begindatum);
$end = strtotime($v->Einddatum);
...
       // echo a ternary statement
   <li><b>Begindatum : " . ($begin ? date("d-m-Y", $begin) : '') . "</b></li>
   <li><b>Einddatum    : " . ($end ? date("d-m-Y", $end) : '') . "</b></li>
```

Comment: ok thanks but how to implement this piece in the code I gave above?

Comment: @PetervanderLely You can put the first two lines right after the `foreach`, the `( ... )` would replace your `date()` stuff.

Comment: Thanks...it works perfect...still have to check for server load: that's the downside of these necessary date conversions within a loop.

Answer (score 1):

write

**Begindatum   : " .($v->Begindatum ? date("d-m-Y",strtotime($v->Begindatum)) : '')."**

**Einddatum    : " .($v->Einddatum ? date("d-m-Y",strtotime($v->Einddatum)) :'')."**